# Update all column at once mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table

```
No A B C D
A1 1 2 0 0
B1 1 1 1 1
C1 1 1 2 3
```

I have to look for all the columns and if any column is > 1 I have to change it to 1. 
So the output will be

```
No A B C D
A1 1 1 0 0
B1 1 1 1 1
C1 1 1 1 1
```

Is there a way to do it all together rather than specifying each column name one by one in the `update` query. My real table has 185 columns.

Comment: nope, not really. Not in plain sql. You could query information_schema to get the field names and build a 185-column update query dynamically, but then that's not plain sql anymore. You'd also probably spend more time debugging your sql-generation logic than it'd take to cut/paste all the field names and format them into a monolithic update

Comment: @MarcB Thanks.. Ya i was doing that.. I thought there would be a more elegant way to do it..

Comment: Are you stuck with this schema?  If not, you could refactor to 3 tables, one of which has columns like "Item", "Attribute" and "Value".

Comment: @Rick - EAV tables have their own set of issues, which can make future queries extremely difficult.  They _do_ have their place, but don't need to be used often.  That said, 185 columns seems a bit too wide, so it could probably use another look (different question/site, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward using `information_schema`.

For example:

```
set group_concat_max_len = 4294967295;

select concat(
  'update ',
  table_schema,
  '.',
  table_name,
  ' set ',
  group_concat(concat(' ',column_name,' = least(',column_name,',1)')),
  ';'
) as update_stmt 
into outfile '/tmp/update_all_the_columns.sql'
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'your_schema'
and table_name = 'your_table';

\. /tmp/update_all_the_columns.sql
```